# Outer Measure definition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In the definition of Lebesgue outer measure/ outer measure , 
$m^*(A) = inf \{\sum l(I_n)\}$
Here how can one take infimum over a summation?
Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set is really the *sum* of the lengths, not necessarily the summation itself. So we are looking at the set of all possible positive, real numbers $S$ such that $S=\sum \ell(I_n)$ for some countable collection of intervals $\{I_n\}$ which covers $A$. The set is composed of real numbers and is bounded below by $0$, so we can find the infimum.

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* an infimum over a summation. It is the infimum of a *set*. Actually of a subset of $[0,+\infty]$. The elements in the set are all written as summations, though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/f/4/ef4a90e03d1c6f075eded2001ee4c0a4.png

So the infimum is taken over a set of sequences of open intervals. It is well defined because the set of all these sums is non-empty and bounded by zero.